# Securing Kubernetes Service with TLS

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, tls1.2, kubernetes-security, kubernetes-service

I have an application that is internal and exposed only to other application on the cluster by a service with cluster IP. Other services are accessing this application via it's DNS (`serviceName-namespace.svc.cluster.local`). This application handles sensitive data, so although all the communication is inside the cluster I would like to use TLS to secure the communications to this application.

My question is - how can I enable TLS on a service? Is there something already exist or should I handle it on the application code? Also, is there already a CA I can use on the cluster that can sign certificates for `.svc.cluster.local`?

To clarify, I know I can use ingress for this purpose. The only problem is keeping this service internal only - so only services inside the cluster will be able to access it.

Thanks,
Omer

Comment: Did you check out Jetstack's [cert-manager](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/) project already?

Comment: No, but now after taking a quick look - I'm not sure this will work for internal services, with internal DNS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found that Kubernetes API can be used to generate a certificate that will be trusted by all the pods running on the cluster. This option might be simpler than the alternatives. You can find the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/), including full flow of generating a certificate and using it.

Comment: Interesting, and easier than my answer. +1

Comment: Does this work OK for you?  The documentation you linked to describes putting the pod IPs as SANs in the certificate.  Surely these will change on a regular basis when the pod is recycled and become invalid?

Comment: I did not play with it yet. If I'll have the chance, I'll give it a try and update

Comment: @OmerLeviHevroni: Is it working with this solution? Also, the document says `Now you can use server.crt and server-key.pem as the keypair to start your HTTPS server.` What does it mean? `example.default.svc.cluster.local` is default URL for all services. Where do we need to provide that certificate?

Comment: You need to provide them to your service to start the TLS connection. It really depend on the stack - different technologies have different configuration options for that.

Comment: I provide certificate information in `nginx` ingress for publically facing domains. But, there is no ingress for `default.svc.cluster.local` domains. Not sure how can I configure it.

Comment: yes, you will have to handle TKS directly in your code - or use tools like Istio that handle the TLS for you

Comment: hey hi, I followed this ref (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/) I am struck with same question  Now you can use server.crt and server-key.pem as the keypair to start your HTTPS server. What does it mean? example.default.svc.cluster.local is default URL for all services. Where do we need to provide that certificate? @OmerLeviHevroni

Comment: You need to provide it you your server on start so it could use it to serve TLS traffic, which language are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Following @vonc comments from bellow, I think I have a solution:

- Purchase a public valid domain for this service (e.g. `something.mycompany.com`).
- Use CoreDNS to add override rule so all requests to `something.mycompany.com` will go to `something-namesapce.svc.cluster.local`, as the service is not exposed externally (this can be done also with normal A record for my use case).
- Use Nginx or something else to handle TLS with the certificate for `something.mycompany.com`.

This sounds pretty complicated but might work. What do you think?

Comment: the Service works at Layer 4 mate... what you're saying is Layer 7 has nothing to do with this...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the tutorial "[Secure Kubernetes Services with Ingress, TLS and LetsEncrypt](https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/secure-kubernetes-services-with-ingress-tls-letsencrypt/)" could apply to you:

> Ingress can be backed by different implementations through the use of different Ingress Controllers. The most popular of these is the [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/controllers/nginx), however there are other options available such as [Traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/), [Rancher](https://github.com/rancher/lb-controller), [HAProxy](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/tree/master/examples/deployment/haproxy), etc. Each controller should support a basic configuration, but can even expose other features (e.g. rewrite rules, auth modes) via annotations.
>
> Give it a domain name and enable TLS. [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a free TLS certificate authority, and using the [kube-lego](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego) controller we can automatically request and renew LetsEncrypt certificates for public domain names, simply by adding a few lines to our Ingress definition!
>
> In order for this to work correctly, a public domain name is required and should have an A record pointing to the external IP of the Nginx service.

For limiting to inside the cluster domain though (`svc.cluster.local`), [you might need CoreDNS](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/).

Comment: I know this can be done with ingress, I used ingress a couple of times before. I don't want to use ingress because I want to keep this service internal (e.g, accessible only from inside the cluster). It seems that it might be possible by reading [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1407), but this seems a bit complicated. Also, what certificate shuld I use?

Comment: @OmerLeviHevroni You can use a self-signed certificate for testing (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#securing-the-service)

Comment: I know, but that doesn't sound like a something I would like to use in production. This means I should roll the self-signed certificate to each client consuming this service.

Comment: @OmerLeviHevroni Agreed: at work we are using a wildcard certificate managed by F5 (our proxy: https://f5.com/glossary/reverse-proxy)

Comment: F5 is running on the cluster and acting as the CA? I am not familiar with it enough so sorry if this is a trivial question. Also, this sounds like expensive solution...

Comment: Yes,  I don't have a generic solution, I was just pointing out what we do.

Answer (score -5):

On Google Cloud you can make load balancer service internal, like this:

```
    annotations = {
      "cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type" = "Internal"
    }
```